# Is there any $k$ such that there are no primes with $k$ digits?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

It seems that for any base $b\geq 2$, and for any number of digits $k\geq 2$, there is always some prime number that is $k$ digits long in base $b$.

For example, in base $10$, for $2\leq k\leq 10$ we have

$$\{11, 101, 1009, 10007, 100003, 1000003, 10000019, 100000007, 1000000007, 10000000019\}$$

and in base $2$ we have

$$\left\{11_2,101_2,1011_2,10001_2,100101_2,1000011_2,10000011_2,100000001_2,1000001001_2,10000000111_2\right\}$$

are there any counterexamples to this or is there a proof that this is always the case?

Comment: Look up "Bertrand's postulate."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Bertrand's postulate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_postulate) (proven later by Chebyshev) says that for any $n>1$, there exists some prime $p$ such that $n<p<2n$.

In particular, for base $b\ge2$ with $k\ge2$, this gives us that there exists a prime strictly between $b^{k-1}$ and $2b^{k-1}$, so we have that there exists a $k$-digit prime base $b$.